# LoDash challenges, I have an array of objects I need to filter, for an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, lodash

I have the following array of objects that I need to filter by `_id` using an array of `_id` values.

```
var objects = [{
    _account: "YzzrzBrO9OSzo6BXwAvVuL5dmMKMqkhOoEqeo",
    _id:      "055z5gzVyVfzlBnEOqYvcoLL1ZgOWJhkrWMkv2"
}, {
    _account: "YzzrzBrO9OSzo6BXwAvVuL5dmMKMqkhOoEqeo",
    _id:      "LvvrvyrOGOS2e5yE0Bdki45Y1ndVlgfoZ2zoOp"
}, {
    _account: "mjj9jp92z2fD1mLlpQYZI1gAd4q4LwTKmBNLz",
    _id:      "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wRziKlMRPqaYztnR4vn61"
}, {
    _account: "AaaraZrLqLfzRYoAPlb6ujPELWVW4dTK4eJWj",
    _id:      "944r40rPgPU2nXqzMYolS5nyo6Eo9OuqrlDkB"
}, {
    _account: "AaaraZrLqLfzRYoAPlb6ujPELWVW4dTK4eJWj",
    _id:      "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wZ9uey62Pjy5YTqgYGDK"
}];

var id_values = [
    "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wZ9uey62Pjy5YTqgYGDK",
    "944r40rPgPU2nXqzMYolS5nyo6Eo9OuqrlDkB",
    "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wRziKlMRPqaYztnR4vn61"
];
```

I believe that `difference`, `pull` or `without` could be useful but I can't tell them apart from the documentation on LoDash. I also think `forEach`, `forIn` or `uniq` could be useful. I was able to filter one of the objects out using `reject`:

```
_.reject(objects, {
    _id: "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wZ9uey62Pjy5YTqgYGDK"
});
```

Still this does not help me with the need to filter by an array. The result should be the following array:

```
var result = [{
    _account: "YzzrzBrO9OSzo6BXwAvVuL5dmMKMqkhOoEqeo",
    _id:      "055z5gzVyVfzlBnEOqYvcoLL1ZgOWJhkrWMkv2"
}, {
    _account: "YzzrzBrO9OSzo6BXwAvVuL5dmMKMqkhOoEqeo",
    _id:      "LvvrvyrOGOS2e5yE0Bdki45Y1ndVlgfoZ2zoOp"
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fastest way I know how to do it using LoDash:

```js
var objects = [{
    _account: "YzzrzBrO9OSzo6BXwAvVuL5dmMKMqkhOoEqeo",
    _id:      "055z5gzVyVfzlBnEOqYvcoLL1ZgOWJhkrWMkv2"
}, {
    _account: "YzzrzBrO9OSzo6BXwAvVuL5dmMKMqkhOoEqeo",
    _id:      "LvvrvyrOGOS2e5yE0Bdki45Y1ndVlgfoZ2zoOp"
}, {
    _account: "mjj9jp92z2fD1mLlpQYZI1gAd4q4LwTKmBNLz",
    _id:      "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wRziKlMRPqaYztnR4vn61"
}, {
    _account: "AaaraZrLqLfzRYoAPlb6ujPELWVW4dTK4eJWj",
    _id:      "944r40rPgPU2nXqzMYolS5nyo6Eo9OuqrlDkB"
}, {
    _account: "AaaraZrLqLfzRYoAPlb6ujPELWVW4dTK4eJWj",
    _id:      "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wZ9uey62Pjy5YTqgYGDK"
}];

var id_values = [
    "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wZ9uey62Pjy5YTqgYGDK",
    "944r40rPgPU2nXqzMYolS5nyo6Eo9OuqrlDkB",
    "rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wRziKlMRPqaYztnR4vn61"
];

var index  = index_of_array(id_values);

var result = _.reject(objects, function (object) {
    return index[object._id] || false;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/2.1.0/lodash.compat.js"></script>

<script>
/*
  Creates an index of an array of keys. Allows you to check whether the array
  has a specific key in O(1) time (as compared to O(n) time using indexOf). It
  takes O(n) time to create the index where n is the length of the array.

  e.g.

  var keys  = [1,2,3];
  var index = index_of_array(keys);     //         O(n) time
  console.log(index[1] || false);       // true  - O(1) time
  console.log(index[4] || false);       // false - O(1) time
  console.log(keys.indexOf(1) >= 0);    // true  - O(n) time
  console.log(keys.indexOf(4) >= 0);    // false - O(n) time
*/

function index_of_array(array) {
    var length = array.length
      , result = {}
      , index  = 0;

    while (index < length)
        result[array[index++]] = true;
    return result;
}
</script>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just try following

```
var data = [{ _account: 'YzzrzBrO9OSzo6BXwAvVuL5dmMKMqkhOoEqeo',
    _id: '055z5gzVyVfzlBnEOqYvcoLL1ZgOWJhkrWMkv2'},
  { _account: 'YzzrzBrO9OSzo6BXwAvVuL5dmMKMqkhOoEqeo',
    _id: 'LvvrvyrOGOS2e5yE0Bdki45Y1ndVlgfoZ2zoOp'},
  { _account: 'mjj9jp92z2fD1mLlpQYZI1gAd4q4LwTKmBNLz',
    _id: 'rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wRziKlMRPqaYztnR4vn61'},
  { _account: 'AaaraZrLqLfzRYoAPlb6ujPELWVW4dTK4eJWj',
    _id: '944r40rPgPU2nXqzMYolS5nyo6Eo9OuqrlDkB'},
  { _account: 'AaaraZrLqLfzRYoAPlb6ujPELWVW4dTK4eJWj',
    _id: 'rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wZ9uey62Pjy5YTqgYGDK' }];

var ids = ['rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wZ9uey62Pjy5YTqgYGDK', '944r40rPgPU2nXqzMYolS5nyo6Eo9OuqrlDkB', 'rEEwENwnznCQvkm61wRziKlMRPqaYztnR4vn61'];

data = _.filter(data,function(obj){
    return ids.indexOf(obj._id) === -1;
});

console.log(data);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f9ygnnuc/)

Comment: Your answer is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Using `indexOf` is very slow as it takes `O(n)` time test whether an array has a given value. Hence, if `data` is of length `m` then the time complexity of your code will be `O(m * n)` which is really bad. If you make an index of the `ids` then you can test whether the array has a given value in `O(1)` time. Hence, `O(m * n)` time is reduced to `O(m * 1)` time. In addition it takes `O(n)` time to create the index. Hence, the total time complexity is `O(m + n)` which is significantly faster than `O(m * n)`. See my answer for more details.