# Performant way to filtering an array of objects

Tags: javascript, performance, underscore.js

is this a good way to filter out all of the existing objects in an array?

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
        { id: 1, text: 'obj1'}, 
        { id: 2, text: 'obj2'}, 
        { id: 3, text: 'obj3'}
    ], 
    ids = [ 1, 3 ],
    filteredArray = [];

for (var x = 0, len = arrayOfObjects.length; x < len; x++) {
    for (var i = 0, ilen = ids.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (arrayOfObjects[x].id === ids[i]) {
            arrayOfObjects[x] = null;
            break;
        }
    }
}

filteredArray = _.filter(obj, function(o) { return !!(o); });
```

Update: The goal of this is to filter objects out of the arrayOfObjects that match an id in the ids array. So the code above works (filteredArray is [{ id: 2, text: 'obj2'}], but is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Remove all objects from an array?

Comment: You can empty an array by just setting `obj.length = 0`.  If you're trying to do something besides that please describe in words what exactly you're trying to accomplish and show desired inputs and outputs.

Comment: @AmitJoki, thanks, I've added more info.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28357971/783743.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way of doing it:

```js
var array = [
    { id: 1, text: "obj1" }, 
    { id: 2, text: "obj2" }, 
    { id: 3, text: "obj3" }
];

var ids = [1, 3];

var idsIndex = toIndex(ids);

var result = array.filter(function (obj) {
    return !idsIndex.hasOwnProperty(obj.id);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));

function toIndex(array) {
    var length = array.length;
    var result = {};
    var index  = 0;

    while (index < length)
        result[array[index++]] = true;
    return result;
}
```

The documentation of the `toIndex` function is in the following answer (note that it's called `index_of_array` instead): https://stackoverflow.com/a/28358301/783743